# Abstraction Library for Retrofit

Tags: android, retrofit, retrofit2, abstraction, android-networking

I am writing a layer of abstraction on top of Retrofit Network Library so that we can change the Retrofit anytime without much impact on application code.

[image]

And we typically write an interface and Retrofit implementation for interacting with the network.
[image]

To use [Retrofit](https://square.github.io/retrofit/), we create a java interface that maps to server API and get the instance of it using Retrofit class as below

```
public interface GitHubService {
  @GET("users/{user}/repos")
  Call<List<Repo>> listRepos(@Path("user") String user);
}
```

The Retrofit class generates an implementation of the GitHubService interface.

```
Retrofit retrofit = new Retrofit.Builder()
    .baseUrl("https://api.github.com/")
    .build();

GitHubService service = retrofit.create(GitHubService.class);
```

Call remote webserver.

```
Call<List<Repo>> repos = service.listRepos("octocat");
```

Any pointers how can we build these interfaces internally by Abstraction library based on the request received or Is there a better way to write abstraction for it?

I hope I am conveying the point that the way how we use Retrofit is a little different because it expects interface with annotations which our application is not aware of. Otherwise our application will be tightly coupled with Retrofit annotations and classes like Call (see the return type).

Comment: Did you ever figure this out? I'm in the journey of creating an abstraction layer in order to build my own networking module, so other modules can consume it (and avoid adding Retrofit dependencies on all of them).

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like you are just planning to write Retrofit on top of Retrofit. 
Generally, you are not bound to Retrofit specific classes like 'Call'.
Great thing about Retrofit is it's flexibility, it has adapters for almost anything. You can extend them and get any behavior you want:

For example, you can make Retrofit interface return specific Object instead of Call, using [CallAdapter.Factory.](https://square.github.io/retrofit/2.x/retrofit/retrofit2/CallAdapter.Factory.html) Like that:

```
List<Repo> listRepos(@Path("user") String user);
```

Here is some usage [example](https://android.jlelse.eu/building-your-own-retrofit-call-adapter-b198169bab69). Not sure it's you case, just to show the idea.

In general before creating wrapper on top of the library I would suggest to explore Retrofit source code for other extension points, there are plenty of them.